# When use a cache system with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, caching

(sorry if this is duplicated but I couldn't find anything related)

I have an WordPress 3.0.3 instalation with some custom coding and tried the [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) plugin but had some problems...so I've decided to deactivated it.

And now I'm wondering that there are any average number of daily visits that becames necessary the use of a cache system.

I'm not saying with this that I don't want to use a cache system, but only managing priorities.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can also ask/search this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/. :-)

Comment: @stealthyninja cross-posted at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5286/when-use-a-cache-system-with-wordpress

Comment: @stealthyninja: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=cross-posting

Answer (score 2):

> And now I'm wondering that there are any average number of daily visits that becames necessary the use of a cache system.

You'll know when you need one. Believe me. :)

Seriously: If request times become unbearably long, or the server gets resource problems in peak times, you need caching. That said, it is my opinion that it is never too early to cache a Wordpress blog. Also, loading times can influence your blog's Google rankings which may be a reason to activate caching even though visitor numbers are still low, and not causing problems for the server.

Anything more detailed is really hard to tell because servers differ massively. Some can deal with a larger number of simultaneous Wordpress requests than others, depending on equipment and setup.

Comment: @foxtrot yeah. I added a paragraph.